# How do I prove that $A^{t}A$ is not invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose A is an $n × m$ matrix.
Prove that if $n < m$ then $A^{T} A$ is not invertible.

Comment: What do you know about the rank of the product of matrices?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** Use [that](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_%28linear_algebra%29#Properties)
$$\operatorname{rank}(AB)\leq \min\{\operatorname{rank}(A),\operatorname{rank}(B)\}$$